# STEP files for URDF model

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Ros Users,
I am trying to write an URDF model for Robotiq 2F-140 gripper. http://support.robotiq.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=5963876

Unfortunately only STEP files are provided. Is there a way to use these files to create an URDF file usable in ROS?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262253/step-files-for-urdf-model/) by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2017-05-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-22**:
This is not an answer, but I wanted to point you to [ros-industrial/robotiq](https://github.com/ros-industrial/robotiq). I'm not sure whether or not the 2F-140 is supported already, but might be worth a look. See [ros-industrial/robotiq#97](https://github.com/ros-industrial/robotiq/pull/97).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

URDF only support STL and DAE file formats (as far as I know). If you can only find STEP files you can import those into most CAD programs and export it as a STL easily.

Solidworks is the most popular CAD software but it is expensive. If you don't already have access to it, there are some free ones you can try such as [FreeCAD](https://www.freecadweb.org/).

One small hiccup: if your STEP files don't contain color information then STL will work fine. But STL does not support colors so if your STEP DOES contain color you'll want to use DAE instead of STL, but most CAD packages don't export DAE. Most CAD software WILL export .wrl which can then be imported into [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) and then converted to DAE and color will be maintained.

To summarize:

if STEP file doesn't have color->import STEP into FreeCAD->export as STL

if STEP file does contain color->import STEP into FreeCAD->export as .wrl->import .wrl into Blender->export as DAE

(I know this works with Solidworks, I'm assuming FreeCAD can do it)

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2017-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/33024/pmuthu2s/) on 2019-02-05**:
When I convert WRL format to DAE format using blender, color is lost. Any clue guys?